# How to have common navbar header in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working with nextjs.I want to have common navbar in all the pages .I tried using layout and props children .when I hit on the link the navbar disappears and another page is shown .Below is my code

layout.js

```
 import Header from './Header/header';
 const Layout = ({props}) => (
     <div>
         <Header></Header>
         {props}
     </div>

 );
 export default Layout;
```

app.js

```
 import Layout from '../components/Layout';
 function App() {
     return (
         <Layout>
             <div>

             </div>
         </Layout>  
      )
 }
 export default App;
```

header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../Header/header.css';
import { Menu, Input, Icon } from 'antd';
import Link from 'next/link';


class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navbar">
                <div className="header">
                    <div className="col-1">
                        <div className="logo-section">
                            <img src="../../static/images/logo.png" ></img>    
                            <div >
                                <h3 className="bold">Homelife</h3>            <h3>Care</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="menu-col">
                            <div>
                                    <Link href="/appUser"><a>Seniors with Auth App Users</a></Link>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <Link href="/nonappUser"><a>Seniors without Auth  App Users</a></Link>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default HeaderComponent
```

plzz help

Answer (score 5):

I think you're not destructing right way. the `props` are passed to the component already so you just need to destructure the `children` from the `props`. And you will need to wrap your `Layout` component around all your components so that you can share the components on that page.

```
 import Header from './Header/header';
     const Layout = ({children}) => (
         <div>
             <Header></Header>
             {children}
         </div>

     );
     export default Layout;
```

Comment: Oh wait, you just need to put the `Layout` component around all your components which you want to have the header

Comment: If i do this the content in the textbox of header clears when I switch between components or pages I want it to retain

Comment: IF you haven't solved it maybe you could send a codesandbox and I will check it out properly. I don't understand what you mean